# awk to compare time field for 24 hours data

Tags: datetime, awk, text-processing

I have below test data and I have been able to get data for current date,
How can I compare time to get me data from `00:00:01` to `08:00:00`?

```
Test1   prog  02/20/2017  03:45:56 Success
Test2   prog  02/20/2017  05:21:38 Fail
Test3   prog  02/20/2017  09:35:36 Success
Test4   prog  02/19/2017  06:15:56 Fail
Test5   prog  02/18/2017  07:35:16 Active
Test6   prog  02/19/2017  03:45:56 Success
```

I did

```
a=`date +%m/%d/%Y`
awk -v a="$a" '$3==a' file
```

I have no thoughts on how do I break fourth column i.e.
time to compare it for time range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=$(date +%m/%d/%Y)

awk -F":| *" -v a="$a" '$3==a {t=($4*60*60 + $5*60 + $6); if(t>=1 && t<=28800) print}' File
```

Use `:` and `space sequence` as field seperators. Here, I am converting time to seconds and checking if it's between (inclusive) `1s` and `8hrs`. If then, print the line. Date check is done as the first filter (`$3==a`)

Comment: Is it possible to sort also on this time column?

Comment: Is it possible if date column is varying, as in it searches a=$(date +%m/%d/%Y) from the beginning of the line and when found then calculate time from next field

Comment: @Sid: Like this: `awk -F":| *" -v a="$a" '{i=0; while(++i<=NF){if(match($i, a)){ t=($(i+1)*3600 + $(i+2)*60 + $(i+3)); if(t>=1 && t<=28800) print}}}' File`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v a=`date '+%m/%d/%Y'` '$3$4 ~ a"0[0-8]"' file
```

The above gives required lines for today's date.

If you want all such lines,  then use:

```
awk '$4 ~ "0[0-8]"' file
```

Note that you have to modify the regular expression (the string after `~`) according to your time range.